# Exponential regression [x,y] with numbers.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I would like to build an exponential trendline using numbers.js and then plug that into a D3 chart.

When I look at the [numbers.js API](http://numbers.github.io/statistic.html), however, it sounds like you can only feed Y values into their `numbers.statistic.exponentialRegression()`[function](http://numbers.github.io/statistic.html). My starting point for the analysis is a scatter plot where each y value has an associated x value. Does numbers.js support this?

Pseudo code:

```
numbers.statistic.exponentialRegression(data);
```

where data is an array built as follows:

```
[[x,y],[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]....[xn,yn]]
```